# Haskell SOEGraphics window wont close

Tags: haskell, graphics, io

I am currently following the exercises the in the book: "The Haskell School of Expression" and have reached the third chapter on creating graphics. The book uses the [SOEGraphics](http://cvs.haskell.org/Hugs/pages/libraries/HGL/Graphics-SOE.html) module and demonstrates drawing some simple text in a window and then closing it with a button press.

However, when after compiling and executing, I find that although the window appears with the text on screen, the window refuses to close regardless of which keys I press or whether the focus is on the command line or the window itself.

Here is the source code from the book:

```
module Main where
import SOE
main =  runGraphics(
        do  w <- openWindow
                "My First Graphics Program" (300, 300)
            drawInWindow w (text(100,200) "HelloGraphicsWorld")
            k <- getKey w
            closeWindow w
        )
```

The only way to get the window to close is by forcing it to quit with CTRL-C. Is there something I have overlooked with my code? The program was compiled using GHC 7.4.1 and was run on Ubuntu.

Comment: Where did you get the module from? The HGL package on hackage doesn't build with GHC >= 7, as far as I can see.

Comment: Perhaps I am confused about which libraries I am referring to? I followed the instructions to get SOEGraphics working [here](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/hudak/SOE/software1.htm)

Comment: Okay, that's a fairly recent source, so it _should_ work. I didn't know that the SOE code has been moved out of HGL again, and your linking to the hugs docs (last release of hugs was September 2006!) made me wonder. I don't know what might cause the hang, though. Could it be buffering, so that the keypress is only sent after pressing `<enter>`? (Unlikely, but the only guess I can offer.)

Comment: I found the same problem, and, after looking into the file SOE.hs, I found a problem: at lines 488 and 489, the two expressions "return ch" and "getKeyEx win False" should be exchanged. Indeed, after changing that, the program works normally. Hope this might be of any value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `getKeyChar` intead of `getKey`. There seems to have been a change in the preferred method to use and/or to the behavior in certain OSs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the [current release](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/hudak/SOE/SOE-20120121.zip) of the SOE package, which was released about 9 months prior to the date of the question. Like the poster of the question, I am running GHCi 7.4.1 on Ubuntu (12.04). I ran into this same issue, but DuckMaestro's answer did not apply:

`getKeyChar` is not defined in any of the modules in the SOE package. However, `getKeyEx` is:

`getKeyEx :: Window -> Bool -> IO Char`

Though undocumented in the SOE package itself, this function appears to emulate its [namesake](http://cvs.haskell.org/Hugs/pages/libraries/HGL/Graphics-HGL-Utils.html#v%3AgetKeyEx) in the `Graphics.HGL.Utils` module.

However, whereas `getKey` is exported from the SOE module, `getKeyEx` is not.

In order to compile and have the window close on a keypress event

1. exported `getKeyEx` from the SOE module
2. in the code quoted in the question, changed `k <- getKey w` to `k <- getKeyEx w True`

Answer (score 0):

Daniel is correct but I found it weird that getKeyEx works when getKey which merely uses getKeyEx does not.  So I looked.  The problem is pretty clear.  Here is the existing code for getKey

```
getKey win = do
  ch <- getKeyEx win True
  if ch == '\x0' then return ch
    else getKeyEx win False
```

Here's what it should be

```
getKey win = do
  ch <- getKeyEx win True
  if ch /= '\x0' then return ch
    else getKeyEx win False
```

Make this fix and getKey works.

Comment: code is in SOE.hs in the SOE/src directory of the source code download for "The Haskell School of Expression"